Different coupling to different kinds of sources?
Context: 1+1 dimensional scalar field coupled to a background electromagnetic field generated by two charges, q and -q situated at the points 0, a, respectively.
This article studies the effect of the backreaction of a charged scalar field with a background electric field (i.e. the background electric field polarizes the vacuum, the charged vacuum generates an electric field which contributes negatively to the background electric field and the Klein-Gordon equations are solved again with this new electric field).
In equation (3.1), they define some dimensionless variables. Among them, the two I am interested in are the dimensionless background electric field $ \lambda = ea^2E $ and the dimensionless charge of the scalar field $ \varepsilon = ea$. These appear when changing from coordinates that go from 0 to a, to coordinates that go from 0 to 1 (rescaling.)
What this is basically saying, is that the coupling to the external source scales different to the coupling to the scalar field.
The action in 'dimensionful' coordinates (i.e. $x\in[0, a]$) looks something like
$$ S[\phi, A_\mu] = \int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0, a] }
d^2x  \left(
 \frac{1}{2} (D_\mu \phi)^* D^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} 
+ A_\mu j^\mu_\text{external}
\right),
 $$
with $D_\mu = \partial_\mu + ieA_\mu$ the gauge covariant derivative. The 'external' source is $$j^\mu_\text{external} = (q \delta(x) - q\delta(x-a), 0).$$
My question is: When rescaling the coordinates, is it possible to retrieve this different scaling of the coupling parameters, namely the one coupling to the external source and the one coupling to the scalar field? Note that this interaction happens 'inside' of the gauge covariant derivative.
I have been stuck on this problem for a shameful amount of time.
